# Vanilla Javascript/DOM exercise help (adding red footer paragraph)

Tags: javascript, css

My HTML Code:

```
 <html>
 <head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" media="screen" title="no title" charset="utf-8">
      <title>Vanilla</title>
 </head>

   <body>
  <section id="header">
  <h1 id="page-title">Vanilla DOM</h1>
  <div id="image-container">
    <img height="100px" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c0/Vanilla_Ice.jpg" alt="Vanilla Ice" />
  </div>
     <p id="description">
      Vanilla JavaScript can be awesome. Here's why.
     </p>
  <ul id="awesome-list">
    <li class="awesome-list-item">It is built into JavaScript.</li>
    <li class="awesome-list-item">Everybody loves vanilla.</li>
    <li class="awesome-list-item">Everybody loves Vanilla.</li>
  </ul>
</section>

<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts.js"></script>
   </body>
   </html>
```

What I want to do is add a red footer paragraph to the page with the id "page-footer". Because it is a footer paragraph, I'm assuming it has to be placed after the closing section tag. This is what I attempted but doesn't work:

```
 var redFooter = document.createElement("id");
 redFooter.setAttribute("id", "page-footer");
 redFooter.setAttribute("style", "color: red;"); 
 var section = document.getElementById("header"); 
 section.appendChild(redFooter); 
 var redFooter = document.getElementByClass("page-footer");
 var newParagraph = "This is a new red paragraph";
 redFooter.innerHTML = newParagraph;
```

I would like to know what I am doing wrong. Can someone point out the issue? Thank You.

Comment: You are appending the footer to the section Google appendchild

Comment: `document.createElement("id");` is 99.9% likely to be wrong, maybe more...

Comment: What errors do you see on the console?

Answer (score 0):

Simple issue: You're using `getElementByClass` when you should be using `getElementById`:

Here's a working fix (hit "Run snippet" to see it in action):

```js
var redFooter = document.createElement("div");
redFooter.setAttribute("id", "page-footer");
redFooter.setAttribute("style", "color: red;"); 
document.getElementById("header").appendChild(redFooter); 
var redFooter = document.getElementById("page-footer");
var newParagraph = "This is a new red paragraph";
redFooter.innerHTML = newParagraph;
```

```html
<body>
    <section id="header">
        <h1 id="page-title">Vanilla DOM</h1>
        <div id="image-container">
            <img height="100px" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c0/Vanilla_Ice.jpg" alt="Vanilla Ice" />
        </div>
        <p id="description">Vanilla JavaScript can be awesome. Here's why.</p>
        <ul id="awesome-list">
            <li class="awesome-list-item">It is built into JavaScript.</li>
            <li class="awesome-list-item">Everybody loves vanilla.</li>
            <li class="awesome-list-item">Everybody loves Vanilla.</li>
        </ul>
    </section>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

To insert the footer as a sibling to header, try insertBefore nextSibling of header. This will make sure that the footer appears after the section tag.

```js
var redFooter = document.createElement("section");
 redFooter.setAttribute("id", "page-footer");
 redFooter.setAttribute("style", "color: red;"); 
 var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0]; 
  body.insertBefore(redFooter,document.getElementById("header").nextSibling);
var p = document.createElement("p");
p.setAttribute("id","footer-para");
redFooter.appendChild(p);
p.innerHTML = "This is a new red paragraph";
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" media="screen" title="no title" charset="utf-8">
      <title>Vanilla</title>
 </head>

   <body>
  <section id="header">
  <h1 id="page-title">Vanilla DOM</h1>
  <div id="image-container">
    <img height="100px" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c0/Vanilla_Ice.jpg" alt="Vanilla Ice" />
  </div>
     <p id="description">
      Vanilla JavaScript can be awesome. Here's why.
     </p>
  <ul id="awesome-list">
    <li class="awesome-list-item">It is built into JavaScript.</li>
    <li class="awesome-list-item">Everybody loves vanilla.</li>
    <li class="awesome-list-item">Everybody loves Vanilla.</li>
  </ul>
</section>

<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts.js"></script>
   </body>
   </html>
```